# Validating sql date type in java

Tags: java, sql, regex, validation

I need to validate a form for a person in java with regex codes and I need to check if its not empty.
So a form with a persons name, first name and date of birth.
The date of birth parameter is a java.sql.date type, anyone has any idea on how to use validation with this type of parameter?
Tried the matches() and equals() method but this does not work.

Comment: Please write your code.

Comment: solved already but thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it to `String` and then validate it with `matches()`.

Comment: yh this works thx! :)

Comment: Please mark it as an answer.